# F# -> Access the x. from a let

Tags: f#

As the title says, then I want to access x. from a let instead of a member.

The following works:

```
type UploadController() =
    inherit Controller()

    member x.UploadPath 
        with get() = x.Server.MapPath "~/Uploads"
```

But this:

```
type UploadController() =
    inherit Controller()

    let uploadPath = x.Server.MapPath "~/Uploads"
```

Throws a compiler error:

> The namespace or module 'x' is not
>   defined

Mission impossible?

Comment: This question might be better titled "how do I access `this` from inside a class constructor?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a reference like this:

```
type UploadController () as x =
    inherit Controller ()

    let uploadPath = x.Server.MapPath "~/Uploads"
```

Comment: how come that when I compile and run it, then it throw an exception that says: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the line where `uploadPath` is declared?

Comment: I believe this would be because of how the MVC framework works.

The let uploadPath code is being called in your UploadController constructor, which means the MVC framework has not had time to assign the Server variable to your controller.

It would look something like this:

var controller = new UploadController(); (your logic fires here)
controller.Server = SomeServerSettings;

Answer (score 4):

ChaosPandion has given the general answer, but it's probable that you don't need a self-identifier in your specific case. Assuming `Server` is defined in `Controller` or one of its base classes, you can use `base.` instead of a self-identifier. This is described in the [F# docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx):

> The keyword **`base`** is available in derived classes and refers to the base class instance. It is used like the self-identifier.